# VB.NET regular expression matching alternating letters and numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex

Hi I'm trying to create a Regular Expression that will match the following conditions:
- A string must have 6 characters
- The pattern must be letter then number and repeat (letter must show up first), so for example:  a1a1a1

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Please show what you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use backreferences to refer to previous captures. Here's a sample regex:

```
([a-z]\d)\1{2}
```

The `\1` means "capture group 1" and `{2}` means repeated twice. Capture group 1 is the part in parentheses, which starts with a letter (`[a-z]`) and is followed by a digit (`\d`).

Comment: Very simple and effective.  Thank you!